# Fix ownership on user directories Windows 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a bunch of user directories on a Unix server not attached to active directory, but, nearly all the directories are named the same thing as their username in AD. I'm migrating my file server over to Windows, which is bound to AD, but the permissions aren't moving over.

What I need to do is somehow `chown` (`takeown`) all the directories in that user folder over to their AD user. In *nix, I'd do something like this:

```
cd /home
find * --max-depth 0 -exec chown -R {} {} \;
```

But I can't seem to find anything with PowerShell that will do it. I get 90% of the way there, but end up with errors that it can't assign ownership, etc. This MAY be due to the `SeRestorePrivilege`, etc, but setting those doesn't seem to help either.

Does anyone have a suggestions, a solution, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File ownership doesn't matter as much in Windows as it does in Linux/Unix, because Windows ACLs are far more versatile than traditional Unix permissions. Just pass ownership to the Administrators group and grant full permissions to SYSTEM, the Administrators group, and the user whose directory it is, replacing the existing permissions. Use [`takeown`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) and [`icacls`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) to do so.

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\home' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  $path = $_.FullName
  $user = $_.Name

  & takeown /f "$path" /r /a
  & icacls "$path" '/grant:r' 'SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F' 'Administrators:(OI)(CI)F' "DOMAIN\${user}:(OI)(CI)F"
}
```

Add read/execute permissions for other users/groups as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you!! Only issue is "takeown" seems to be throwing an error:

`takeown.exe : ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'J:\Users\username'.
At C:\ps\fix_user_permissions2.ps1:5 char:3
+   & takeown "$path" /r /a
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Invalid ...J:\Users\username'.:String) [ 
   ], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Type "TAKEOWN /?" for usage.`

That said, the icacls worked. So... not sure I care. =)

Comment: @staze Sorry, it should've been `takeown /f "$path" /r /a`, not `takeown "$path" /r /a`. Fixed.